# AngularJS ng-model in custom directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a directive with `ng-model`. So I can pass the model to these directives.

Here is what I think about it:

**app.js**

```
app.directive('testDir', function(){
    return {
        templateUrl: 'assets/views/dir.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        required: 'ngModel'

    };
});
```

**dir.html**

```
<div>
    <h1>Test directive</h1>
    <h3>{{name}}</h3>
</div>
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <test-dir ng-model="user"></test-dir>
</div>
```

and the **contoller**

```
$scope.user = {
        name: 'John Doe'
    };
```

I can see the `<h1>` tag with `Test directive` text but nothing in the `<h3>` 
tag

I know it is a very beginner problem, but right know I can't find any solution.

Thank you!

Comment: you not use value from `ngModel` attribute, why you think that it should be bind to `name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `scope` was missing. Please see a working example below

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: 'John Doe'
  };
});

app.directive('testDir', function() {
  return {
    //templateUrl: 'assets/views/dir.html',
    template: '<div>' +
      '<h1>Test directive</h1>' +
      '<h3>{{fooModel.name}}</h3>' +
      '</div>',
    restrict: 'E',
    required: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
        fooModel: '=ngModel'
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa" class="container" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <test-dir ng-model="user"></test-dir>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try This, you need to create a scope variable for ng-model

```
app.directive('testDir', function(){
        return {
            templateUrl: 'assets/views/dir.html',
            restrict: 'E',
            required: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                ngModel:'='
            }

        };
    });
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <h1>Test directive</h1>
    <h3>{{ngModel}}</h3>
</div>
```